# How to highlight max value in the group in Bokeh?

Tags: bokeh

I am trying to highlight the max value in the dataframe for each group in a bar chart.

When I say highlight, it can be one of the following,
Let us say, I want to have striped bar for the max bar in each group. 
Or keep a star/diamond above the bar with max value in the group.
Or connect max bar per group through a line to indicate the trend(like in the below example).

To narrow it to one particular precise query:

In the below plot, for each group, I want to place a circle on the top of a bar (within that group) which is tallest (within that group).

```
from bokeh.io import show, output_file
from bokeh.models import FactorRange
from bokeh.plotting import figure

output_file("mixed.html")

factors = [
    ("Q1", "jan"), ("Q1", "feb"), ("Q1", "mar"),
    ("Q2", "apr"), ("Q2", "may"), ("Q2", "jun"),
    ("Q3", "jul"), ("Q3", "aug"), ("Q3", "sep"),
    ("Q4", "oct"), ("Q4", "nov"), ("Q4", "dec"),

]

p = figure(x_range=FactorRange(*factors), plot_height=250,
           toolbar_location=None, tools="")

x = [ 10, 12, 16, 9, 10, 8, 12, 13, 14, 14, 12, 16 ]
p.vbar(x=factors, top=x, width=0.9, alpha=0.5)

p.line(x=["Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4"], y=[12, 9, 13, 14], color="red", line_width=2)

p.y_range.start = 0
p.x_range.range_padding = 0.1
p.xaxis.major_label_orientation = 1
p.xgrid.grid_line_color = None

show(p)
```

Comment: It's not really clear what you want to accomplish. By highlight I first assumed this would be about hover highlighting but it seems to have nothing to do with that. Please elaborate on what you are trying to do (a rough sketch might help)

Comment: @bigreddot let me know if the revised query statement is precise.

Comment: Still a little confused. If you want to e.g. draw a circle on the highest bar in each group, you should figure out which bar has the highest value in each group, and draw a circle there in the same way you would draw a circle anywhere. Is there some question you have about the mechanics of doing that? (E.g how to find the max per-group? How to position with nested categorical coordinates? Something else specific?) Or are you asking if there is something *automatic* that would do it for you? (There is not)

Comment: @bigreddot : How to position a circle on the max per group  with nested categorical coordinates ?

Comment: Are you having a problem with the "max per group" part? Or the "position with nested coordinates" part? I am tying to get you to narrow things down to one single issue. Maybe an even better question, I should have started with: *what have you actually, already tried? And where/how did it go wrong?* SO is not a code-writing site, it is for answering specific issues with specific code that already exists in some form.